# Drop brackets around reference item in `natbib`

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am writing for a journal (Transportation Research Record) that has strange and particular bibliographic guidelines. I've been able to adapt `natbib` to work for the in-text citations. But the bibliography prints brackets around the item numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
    \usepackage[round,sort,numbers]{natbib}
    \newcommand{\trbcite}[1]{({\it\citenum{#1}})}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is an example citation \trbcite{Mokhtarian2008}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `bibfile.bib` containing

```
@article{Mokhtarian2008,
author = {Mokhtarian, Patricia L. and Cao, Xinyu},
doi = {10.1016/j.trb.2007.07.006},
issn = {01912615},
journal = {Transportation Research Part B: Methodological},
keywords = {built environment,causality,land use,residential location,smart growth},
month = mar,
pages = {204--228},
title = {{Examining the impacts of residential self-selection on travel behavior: A focus on methodologies}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0191261507000744},
volume = {42},
year = {2008}
}
```

Any easy ways to do this? Or is this something that will require the .bst file?

Comment: This has been answered before. Add to the preamble `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\makeatother`

Comment: I couldn't find it through the search functions. Thanks for answering.

Comment: No problem. I also couldn't find it (and I am the one who answered this before) ;-)

Comment: Is this command outdated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to the preamble

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1} 
\makeatother
```

Not related to the question, but `\it` is an old command that shouldn't be used anymore; use `\itshape` instead.

Comment: You saved my life :-) thank you sooo much!! fwiw in my case it was `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}`