# Remove square brackets from bibliography list

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

I have seen that
[BibLaTeX bibliography without square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142916/biblatex-bibliography-without-square-brackets)
provides an answer to how to remove square brackets in this example. However, I do not know from that answer where those adjustments can be made because I do not have any of the commands this post cites.

I wish to remove the square brackets and the numbers from the bibliography list as seen in the picture. Moreover, I wish to remove the indentation that comes through this numbering.

I have tried as kindly suggested to use `\makeatletter \renewcommand(...)` as seen in the comment section but that did not change anything. Perhaps, it needs addressing where to put the individual command.

[image: Sample Bibliography]

I am using as bibliography style the file `ecta.bst` which is available here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/ecta.bst .

I am using the `natbib` package which is required for the `ecta.bst` bibliography style.

Here is a test document that is standalone save the `.bib` file which I am also providing in an abbreviated version.

I am trying to achieve the following:

I wish to remove the square-bracketed numbering from the bibliography altogether, which, as I was kindly told includes removing the indentation as well. So I just wish to have the last names in an alphabetically ordered list.

Thank you so much!

See for `.tex` file below and below that the content of the `bibo.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[aps,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter

\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\newcommand\mycite[1]{% with Numbers 
\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})\@
}
%%%%%Here is the command to be tried out.
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%End of Jerome's custom area
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace{0.6cm}

\title{Test Document}

\author{Me}

%
\date{2 December, 2014}
%

\maketitle

\section{Testing Citations}

As he said, \mycite{ECTA:ECTA438}, we need to be clear on testing. Also, \mycite{RefWorks:14} will play a role. When we now add \mycite{RefWorks:12}.

\section{Introduction}

Hello Intro.

\bibliographystyle{ecta}

\bibliography{bibo}{}

\end{document}
```

WITH BIBLIOGRAPHY FILE:

```
@article{RefWorks:12,
    Abstract = {Abstract.},
    Author = {Sophocles Mavroeidis and Mikkel Plagborg-M{\o}ller and James H. Stock},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-14 22:54:50 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Economic Literature},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {124-188},
    Title = {Empirical evidence on inflation expectations in the New Keynesian Phillips Curve},
    Volume = {52},
    Year = {2014}
}
@article{RefWorks:14,
    Abstract = {Abstract.},
    Author = {Kang Yong Tan and David Vines},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-15 13:45:29 +0000},
    Journal = {Available at SSRN 1026339},
    Title = {Woodford goes to Africa},
    Year = {2007}}
@article{ECTA:ECTA438,
    Abstract = {Abstract},
    Author = {Moreira, Marcelo J.},
    Date-Added = {2015-01-14 22:57:58 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-01-14 22:57:58 +0000},
    Doi = {10.1111/1468-0262.00438},
    Issn = {1468-0262},
    Journal = {Econometrica},
    Keywords = {Instruments, similar tests, Wald test, score test, likelihood ratio test, confidence regions, 2SLS estimator, LIML estimator},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {1027--1048},
    Publisher = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
    Title = {A Conditional Likelihood Ratio Test for Structural Models},
    Url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/1468-0262.00438},
    Volume = {71},
    Year = {2003}}
```

Comment: Since you are using BibTeX, you need this answer instead: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119860/3954 i.e., `\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1} 
\makeatother`

Comment: Hah thanks @GonzaloMedina I am just wondering, I miswrote and actually wish to remove the entire numbering, so both number and bracket. Is that covered there as well?

Comment: No explicitly, but the change is simple: `\makeatletter \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} \makeatother`

Comment: Do you also want to suppress indentation? If this is so, please add this new info to your question and in this way, it shouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: Oh wow thank you @GonzaloMedina but what is indented here?

Comment: The items in the bibliography will still have some indentation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Where do I put that `\makeatletter \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} \makeatother` ? I have a preamble that begins with \makeat... and ends with \makeatother and put your command there but it doesn't change anything. Could it be that it is inside the bst file?

Comment: No; that should go in the preamble of your `.tex` file

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Hm I put that into my .tex file and it does not change anything. Should it be by the bibliography command?

Comment: No. If this is not giving the desired result, please compose a little, yet *complete*, test document with the relevant settings you are using so we can test possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much @GonzaloMedina I have provided a brief but workable example and the bibliography as well. For some reason, the command you provided doesn't have bite here. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi. I just did a test with your code and my suggestion indeed works! Did you regenerate the bibliography? Did you run bibtex again after adding the lines I suggested? I mean, after adding the code I suggested, process your document through pdflatex, *then bibtex* and then pdflatex twice-

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you so much for trying! Sadly however, my system, even with the usual latex bibtext 2x latex procedure still just ignores the commands when I take the code exactly as given in my question. Could it be that the renewcommand command is not recognized? (Although it does complain when I tried out leaving both brackets blank.)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It works now. Would you also know how to indent the next line when there is a line break from the title of a paper? So what happened was that I had to put the command you suggested right above the bibliography. Thank you so much for helping me. Again thank you so very much!