# Using Springers spbasic.bst in Overleaf template

Tags: bibtex, citing, overleaf, springernature

I am using the [Overleaf latex template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq) provided by Springer Nature for my Journal paper.

According to International Journal of Data Science and Analytics (JDSA) [submission guidelines](https://www.springer.com/journal/41060/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors_References) it is advised to use 'spbasic.bst' which will generate following citations:

```
8. Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential 
equations. Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)
```

Now within Overleaf the equivalent bib file is 'sn-basic' as stated in the file comments stating "This is file `spbasic.bst', generated with the docstrip utility". However, the generated citation are different and looks like below:

```
[8] Hamburger C (1995) Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential 
equations. Ann Mat Pura Appl 169(2):321–354
```

For MWE, please access this [Overlef template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq) and then just change the document class (as directed by journal guidelines) to

```
\documentclass[sn-basic, Numbered, iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout
```

I have used this document class because guidelines states "choose the formatting option “[iicol]”". And the only commented document class including this option was "\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}". I have just added following two options "sn-basic, Numbered" to it in-place of default.

Please guide me as what am I doing wrong. As this is very basic but still I am not able to get it right.

Comment: Are you sure that the `spbasic` and `sn-basic` bibliography styles are equivalent?

Comment: @Mico Yes. Because in the file itself it is mentioned that "%% This is file `spbasic.bst',
%% generated with the docstrip utility."

Comment: The fact that the two bib styles produce rather different outputs would indicate that they're *not* equivalent, the material in the files' headers notwithstanding.

Comment: The instructions to use spbasic may be out of date - you should probably use the sn-basic option (it's unfortunate that the comment states that the file is spbasic - it may be that sn-basic was based off spbasic). Even if there is a difference in the way the reference list is printed (square brackets), it's best to go with the template for submission purposes (editors can modify for final printing). If you do want to get rid of the square brackets, you can adapt this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119856/drop-brackets-around-reference-item-in-natbib (add a period).